# How to get the max() amount from a sum() subquery

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, teradata

My sub-query gets me the brand name and sum of the of the sales amount from 2013. My main query is trying to get the brand name and the highest sales amount from that year but this will return duplicate because the query will try to get the max(amount) for each brand name. How do I filter it so it will just return the highest amount with only one brand name? This is my query so far, any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!

```
SELECT
maxamt.brnd_nm, 
MAX(maxamt.amt) AS amt


FROM
(
SELECT 
c.brnd_nm AS BRND_NM,
SUM(b.sales_amt) AS AMT

FROM prd.client  A

INNER JOIN db1.table1  B
ON b.pty_key = a.pty_key
INNER JOIN db1.table2 c
ON b.d_key = c.d_key
INNER JOIN db1.table3 d
ON b.posat_key = d.posat_key
INNER JOIN db1.table4 e
ON b.frmly_key = e.frmly_key
WHERE   B.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' 
    AND '2013-12-31'
    AND b.C_ID IN ( 'abc', 'def', 'wqs')

GROUP BY 1
) MaxAmt
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Have you tried using a where clause instead of the group by, something like Where maxamt.amt = Max(maxamt.amt)

Comment: You can't refer to column aliases in the `WHERE` clause, only in `HAVING`.

Comment: You could always take your results and store them in a Temp table. Then filter the column with the MAX function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use the `TOP` operator?:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (  SELECT  c.brnd_nm AS BRND_NM,
                SUM(b.sales_amt) AS AMT
        FROM prd.client  A
        INNER JOIN db1.table1  B
            ON b.pty_key = a.pty_key
        INNER JOIN db1.table2 c
            ON b.d_key = c.d_key
        INNER JOIN db1.table3 d
            ON b.posat_key = d.posat_key
        INNER JOIN db1.table4 e
            ON b.frmly_key = e.frmly_key
        WHERE   B.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' 
            AND '2013-12-31'
            AND b.C_ID IN ( 'abc', 'def', 'wqs')

        GROUP BY c.brnd_nm) MaxAmt
ORDER BY AMT DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subquery, just use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT 
    c.brnd_nm AS BRND_NM,
    SUM(b.sales_amt) AS AMT

FROM prd.client  A

INNER JOIN db1.table1  B
    ON b.pty_key = a.pty_key
INNER JOIN db1.table2 c
    ON b.d_key = c.d_key
INNER JOIN db1.table3 d
    ON b.posat_key = d.posat_key
INNER JOIN db1.table4 e
    ON b.frmly_key = e.frmly_key
WHERE   B.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' 
    AND '2013-12-31'
    AND b.C_ID IN ( 'abc', 'def', 'wqs')

GROUP BY BRND_NM
ORDER BY AMT DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use QUALIFY plus ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT 
c.brnd_nm AS BRND_NM,
SUM(b.sales_amt) AS AMT

FROM prd.client  A

INNER JOIN db1.table1  B
ON b.pty_key = a.pty_key
INNER JOIN db1.table2 c
ON b.d_key = c.d_key
INNER JOIN db1.table3 d
ON b.posat_key = d.posat_key
INNER JOIN db1.table4 e
ON b.frmly_key = e.frmly_key
WHERE   B.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' 
    AND '2013-12-31'
    AND b.C_ID IN ( 'abc', 'def', 'wqs')

GROUP BY 1
QUALIFY
   ROW_NUMBER() 
   OVER (ORDER BY AMT DESC) = 1
```